# Pepper Plant leaves Wilting, please help

Tags: containers, peppers, chili, hot-weather

Recently bought a pepper plant and transplanted it into a pot. Mulched over the top since its been in the high 80s F recently and I didn't want the soil drying out. Its only been in the pot half a week and was hoping someone could tell me what's wrong with it. It has been in full sun.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't look like the leaves are wilting to me, looks more like sunburn... peppers are able to withstand full sun, but they need to be hardened off slowly if they are coming from a greenhouse environment...

The keys to look for are certain parts will be more effected, like all of the leaves facing a particular direction, tops of exposed stems, etc. Tender new growth, will often be most effected.

Keeping plants moist in clay pots in hot dry climates can be difficult also, but I don't think that is what is pictured.

There are lots of articles written, and videos made about "harden(ing) off" plants... too late for OP, but hopefully helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

your plant is wilting and should probably be watered. This being said extreme wilting causing leaf dryness can increase chances of plant disease. It is hard to tell with just these pictures, but to the untrained eye it might be a disease or a potassium deficiency. To better assess the situation can you give me background info on your irrigation? Did you drop any water by accident on your leaves while irrigating?